# Input and output layers of Keras autoencoder don't match, can't run model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to work on building an autoencoder in Keras, with an input shape of (470,470,3) but the output never seems to match, even when I try to switch around padding. This is my code, can you please help? The way it is currently written my model summary shows an output of (472, 472, 3).

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model

input_image = Input(shape=(470, 470, 3)) 

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_image)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded_image = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_image, decoded_image)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last padding to `'valid'`:

```
decoded_image = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='valid')(x)
```